# scipy.optimize.least_squares and matlab lsqnonlin difference

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I would like to find minimum of equations given in these script. It is looking very messy(but deep undestanding of equation is not needed- I suppose). At the end of `def` is the expression to minimize:

```
 vys1=-Qd-40*sqrt(5)*sqrt((ch+cm)*ep*kb*Na*T)*w1
 vys2=fi0-fib-Q0/cq 
 vys3=fib-fid+Qd/cq1 
 vysf= np.array([vys1,vys2,vys3])
 return vysf
```

I write this script in matlab using `lsqnonlin` to compare the results. Matlab results seems much accurate. Result are (fi0,fib,fid)

```
Python 
[-0.14833481 -0.04824387 -0.00942132] Sum(value) ~1e-3.  
Matlab 
[-0,13253   -0,03253      -0,02131 ] Sum(value)~1e-15
```

Note that script has  a check for typos in equation(if they are identical in python and matlab)
for `[fi0,fib,fid]=[-0.120, -0.0750 ,-0.011]` the result  are the same `[vys1,vys2,vys3]`-

```
python [0.00069376  0.05500097 -0.06179421]
matlab [0.0006937598,0.05500096 -0.06179421]
```

Are there any options in `least_squares` to improve results? Thanks for any help(sorry for misunderstanding english )

Python

```
import scipy as sc
import numpy as np
from math import sinh
import matplotlib as plt
from numpy import exp, sqrt
from scipy.optimize import leastsq,least_squares

def q(par,ep,Na,kb,T,e,gamaal,gamasi,gamax,k1,k2,k3,k4,cq,cq1,ch,cm):
    fi0,fib,fid=np.array([par[0],par[1],par[2]])
    AlOH= gamaal*k1*exp(e*fi0/(T*kb))/(ch + k1*exp(e*fi0/(T*kb)))
    AlOH2= ch*gamaal/(ch + k1*exp(e*fi0/(T*kb)))
    SiO= gamasi*k2*exp(e*fi0/(T*kb))/(ch + k2*exp(e*fi0/(T*kb)))
    SiOH= ch*gamasi/(ch + k2*exp(e*fi0/(T*kb)))
    X= gamax*k3*k4*exp(e*fib/(T*kb))/(ch*k4 + cm*k3 + k3*k4*exp(e*fib/  (T*kb)))
    XH= ch*gamax*k4/(ch*k4 + cm*k3 + k3*k4*exp(e*fib/(T*kb)))
    Xm= cm*gamax*k3/(ch*k4 + cm*k3 + k3*k4*exp(e*fib/(T*kb)))
    Q0=e*(0.5*(AlOH2+SiOH-AlOH-SiO)-gamax)
    Qb=e*(XH+Xm)
    Qd=-Q0-Qb
    w1=sc.sinh(0.5*e*fid/kb/T)
    vys1=-Qd-40*sqrt(5)*sqrt((ch+cm)*ep*kb*Na*T)*w1
    vys2=fi0-fib-Q0/cq 
    vys3=fib-fid+Qd/cq1 
    vysf= np.array([vys1,vys2,vys3])
    return vysf

kb=1.38E-23;T=300;e=1.6e-19;Na=6.022e23;gamaal=1e16;gamasi=1e16
gamax=1e18;k1=1e-4;k2=1e5;k3=1e-4;k4=1e-4;cq=1.6;cq1=0.2
cm=1e-3;ep=80*8.8e-12
ch1=np.array([1e-3,1e-5,1e-7,1e-10])

# Check the equations, if they are same
x0=np.array([-0.120,    -0.0750 ,-0.011])
val=q(x0,ep,Na,kb,T,e,gamaal,gamasi,gamax,k1,k2,k3,k4,cq,cq1,ch1[0],cm)
print(val)
w1=least_squares(q,x0, args=(kb,ep,Na,T,e,gamaal,gamasi,gamax,k1,k2,k3,
                             k4,cq,cq1,ch1[0],cm))
print(w1['x'])
```

matlab

```
function[F1,poten,fval]=test()
kb=1.38E-23;T=300;e=1.6e-19;Na=6.022e23;gamaal=1e16;gamasi=1e16;gamax=1e18;
k1=1e-4;k2=1e5;k3=1e-4;k4=1e-4;cq=1.6;cq1=0.2;ch=[1e-3];cm=1e-3;ep=80*8.8e-   12;
% Test if equation are same 
x0=[-0.120, -0.0750 ,-0.011];
F1=rovnica(x0,ch) ;
[poten,fval]= lsqnonlin(@(c) rovnica(c,ch(1)),x0);
function[F]=rovnica(c,ch) 
fi0=c(1);
fib=c(2);
fid=c(3);
aloh=exp(1).^(e.*fi0.*kb.^(-1).*T.^(-1)).*gamaal.*k1.*(ch+exp(1).^(e.* ...
fi0.*kb.^(-1).*T.^(-1)).*k1).^(-1);
aloh2=ch.*gamaal.*(ch+exp(1).^(e.*fi0.*kb.^(-1).*T.^(-1)).*k1).^(-1);
sioh=ch.*gamasi.*(ch+exp(1).^(e.*fi0.*kb.^(-1).*T.^(-1)).*k2).^(-1);
sio=exp(1).^(e.*fi0.*kb.^(-1).*T.^(-1)).*gamasi.*k2.*(ch+exp(1).^(e.* ...
fi0.*kb.^(-1).*T.^(-1)).*k2).^(-1);
Xm=cm.*gamax.*k3.*(cm.*k3+ch.*k4+exp(1).^(e.*fib.*kb.^(-1).*T.^(-1)) ...
.*k3.*k4).^(-1);
 XH=ch.*gamax.*k4.*(cm.*k3+ch.*k4+exp(1).^(e.*fib.*kb.^(-1).*T.^(-1)) ...
.*k3.*k4).^(-1);
Q0=e*(0.5*(aloh2+sioh-aloh-sio)-gamax);
Qb=e*(XH+Xm);
Qd=-Q0-Qb;
F=[-Qd+(-40).*5.^(1/2).*((ch+cm).*ep.*kb.*Na.*T).^(1/2).*sinh((1/2).*e.* ...
fid.*kb.^(-1).*T.^(-1));...
 fi0-fib-Q0/cq;...
(fib-fid+Qd/cq1)];
 end
end
```

Comment: You should improve your code formatting!!!

Comment: The list of the options that `least_squares` has is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html). The most relevant are the tolerance options, ftol, gtol, and xtol. Decreasing these sometimes improves the outcome of minimization. But not in this case. It looks like MATLAB's lsqnonlin, which benefited from the efforts of its engineering team for over a decade, outperforms least_squares, which was added to SciPy in the summer of last year. You may want to open an issue on SciPy's repo, but it'd be nice to have a simpler function to work with.

Comment: The optimization method in both matlab and in least_squares is afaics trust-region-reflective, so large performance differences are in fact not expected. Counterexamples would indeed be very useful to find, but here it appears the cause is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake in this line:

```
w1=least_squares(q,x0, args=(kb,ep,Na,T,e,gamaal,gamasi,gamax,k1,k2,k3,
                             k4,cq,cq1,ch1[0],cm))
```

You have the argument `kb` in the wrong spot.  The signature of `q` is:

```
def q(par,ep,Na,kb,T,e,gamaal,gamasi,gamax,k1,k2,k3,k4,cq,cq1,ch,cm):
```

The argument `kb` is between `Na` and `T`.  If you fix the `args` argument in the `least_squares` call:

```
w1 = least_squares(q, x0, args=(ep, Na, kb, T, e, gamaal, gamasi, gamax,
                                k1, k2, k3, k4, cq, cq1, ch1[0], cm))
```

then the output of the Python script is

```
[ 0.00069376  0.05500097 -0.06179421]
[-0.13253313 -0.03253254 -0.02131043]
```

which agrees with the Matlab output.